# How do I develop Spring boot application which expose only Rest APIs and authorize requests by Google or GitHub access token?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, restful-authentication

I have developed a spring-boot web application that exposes only restful APIs and those endpoints about to be consumed by angular app or android application.

Now I need to authorize those Restful API request by either Google, Facebook or GitHub OAuth2 access token according to the user preference, I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by using Spring Security. There are plenty of articles you can find on the web. 
Check [this](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-google-oauth) one for example.

Answer (score 0):

Check the oficial Spring Boot guide [Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/). It describes an application which starts with a simple, single-provider single-sign on, and works up to a client with a choice of authentication providers: `GitHub` or `Google`.